# How can i know if data in ListView was changed?

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, qml

I have ListView. Every element has "name" and "amount" roles. I need to count total amount of all elements and show it(For example: "itemA": 10, "itemB": 2. Total amount is 12).
I try to use "onDataChanged", but it shows error: Cannot assign to non-existent property "onDataChanged". How can I handle "data changed" notification in qml?

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);

    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[Qt::UserRole + 1] = "name";
    roles[Qt::UserRole + 2] = "amount";

    QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel();
    model->setRowCount(0);
    model->setItemRoleNames(roles);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myModel", model);

    auto item1 = new QStandardItem();
    item1->setData("item1", Qt::UserRole + 1);
    item1->setData("10", Qt::UserRole + 2);
    model->appendRow(item1);

    auto item2 = new QStandardItem();
    item2->setData("item2", Qt::UserRole + 1);
    item2->setData("1", Qt::UserRole + 2);
    model->appendRow(item2);

    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        ListView {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            model: myModel
            delegate: Text {
                text: name + " " + amount
            }

            onDataChanged: function () {
                var number = 0
                for(var i = 0; i < myModel.rowCount(); i++) {
                    var index = myModel.index(i, 0);
                    number += myModel.data(index, amount)
                }

                total.text = "Total: " + number
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            height: 20
            Text {
                id: total
                anchors.fill: parent
                text: "Total: "
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ListView.data` does not relates to the models data, it is an `Item` property, you should have a property on your model that calculates that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to listen for signals from the model, not the ListView to find out when the data has changed. Try something like this:

```
ListView {
    model: myModel

    Connections {
        target: model

        onDataChanged: function() {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```